# How to save canvas as png file without inform user,

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, png

I want to save my canvas with javafx without implement the showDialog, I can do it with the showDialog but I want to delete it.

```
    public void exportCanvasToPNG(String fileName) {
        // face = Canvase
        if (face != null) {
            WritableImage img = face.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

            FileChooser fChooser = new FileChooser();
            fChooser.setTitle("Sauvegarde preview");
            fChooser.setInitialFileName(fileName);
            fChooser.setInitialDirectory(dir);
            fChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Fichier PNG", "*.png"));

            // selectedFile = File
            selectedFile = fChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);

            try {
                if (selectedFile != null) {
                    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null), "png", selectedFile);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }``
```

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? Just create a file at some target directory and save whatever you want.

Comment: Don't use `FileChooser`.

Comment: yes is that kleopatra, and I would like to do this without the showSaveDialog

Comment: then work through a tutorial on java language basics, in particular about interaction with the file system, apply what you learned to your context and when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void exportCanvasToPNG(String fileName) {
    // face = Canvas
    if (face != null) {
        WritableImage img = face.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        try {
            File outputFile = new File("FaceSnapshot.png");
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null), "png", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !!! swpalmer